# MethodNotAllowedHttpException ruta sin CSRF

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Poso una ruta en laravel la cual es llamada por una funcion en JS y no tengo control de ella debido a que es externa, esta ruta es un metodo post ya que necesito que sea de esa manera pero me genera un MethodNotAllowedHttpException como hago para excluir ciertas rutas de esta validacion.

Nota: ya he probado añadirla en VerifyCsrfToken en su vector de excepciones, modificando ese archivo de class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware a un nuevo archivo llamado class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier con todas sus dependencias y tambien he desabilitado las validaciones en el Middleware pero ninguno me da resultado

Comment: ¿De qué no tienes control, de la ruta de Laravel o de la función de JS?

Comment: Coloca el código que estás probando con el cual no te funciona, para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: estoy realizando una integracion sobre un sitio seguro, la integracion posee una funcion JS, esta llama a una ruta en mi server que debe tener un nombre especifico por ejemplo "mensaje", esta ruta debe ser un metodo post, ya que cuando se ejecuta esa funcion hace un llamado a mi ruta sin yo enviarle algun parametro la misma funcion se encarga de llamar a la ruta, y de la funcion no tengo ningun control hacia el llamado a mi ruta

Comment: que version de laravel estas usando? agrega el codigo que añadiste a VerifyCsrfToken

Comment: namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [ 
        'http://dominio.com/resexdev/public/autentificacion'
        //
    ];
}

la version de laravel es la 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Este tipo de implementaciones suelen ser comunes con pasarelas de pago, lo he hecho muchas veces, sin problema alguno.

El mensaje de error es muy específico:

> la función de JS está utilizando un método (verbo) no permitido

por lo cual debes revisar cual es el método o verbo que está utilizando la función de JS por medio del debug de Laravelo alguna otra herramienta.

Lo que yo haría para detectar dicho método es utilizar Request para determinar lo que está llegando:

```
$method = $request->method();

Log::info($method);
```

Posteriormente simplemente sería adaptar la ruta a lo que esté recibiendo, sea POST, GET, etc...

---

EDICIÓN: Según la información proporcionada en un comentario, veo que la URL que utiliza en la excepción es toda una dirección completa:

```
protected $except = [
    'dominio.com/resexdev/public/autentificacion';
];
```

Aunque considero que esto no tiene NADA que ver con el error, lo mejor sería utilizar la url relativa simplemente, además es incorrecto el punto y coma (;) después de la URL, pues es un array.

```
protected $except = [
    'autentificacion',
];
```

Comment: no entiendo como generar esta accion

Comment: ¿qué no entiendes específicamente?

Comment: listo hermano ya resolvi muchisimas gracias por la ayuda era la configuracion del web server del apache